# How to use only PART of the functionality in nested routes NodeJS

Tags: node.js, routes, authorization, nested-routes

So I have a router `schoolsRouter` where all the school-specific functionality is being handled { login school, adding a new teacher, ...etc.). And I want the `admin` of the app to be able to add and delete new schools. Now the pattern I'm using encapsulates all the routing functionality in one file `schools.routes.js` where the `School` model is exposed. So the `createSchool` and `deleteSchool` routes are in the `schools.routes.js` but I need only the admin to be able to perform those operations and that seems pretty easy with `merged routes` like this (in `admins.routes.js`):

```
adminsRouter.use('/schools/', schoolsRouter);
```

but the problem is that now the admin can access all the other routes in `schools.routes.js` like `schools/login` which is something that I don't want to happen. So how can I make the `adminsRouter` use the create and delete operations from the `schoolsRotuer` without being able to access all these other functionalities? (Keeping in mind I'm using JWT authentication).

Comment: Hey I'd really appreciate it if someone also could help me with titling this question in a better way because it was really hard for me to find a title for such question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use middlewares in the routes that you wish to controll.

This is the middleware that I will name of **admin-middleware.js**

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {    
    if (user.admin === true) {
        return next();
    } else {
        return res.status(403).send('Unauthorized')
    }
}
```

So, this is your route declaration at **schools.routes.js**

```
const adminMiddleware = require('../YOUR_FOLDERS/admin-middleware.js');

schools.delete('/:id', adminMiddleware, (req, res) => {
    return res.send('ok');
});
```

If you wish disregard a route, you can use this validation at your code in the middleware.

```
if(req.originalUrl.includes('/schools/login'))
    return next();
```

I hope that it works to you.

Comment: Hey I still have one issue. How about `login` route? I can't protect that using a middleware because users aren't logged in at that point so how do I tell the `adminsRouter` not to access the `schools/login` route?

Comment: @M.Olaby You can just disregard the middleware at your route or to use the example that I edited above.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks man!